# https file transfer in java

Tags: file, https, file-transfer

I  need to transfer a file between two computers using https protocol using a java code. I have no idea where to start at. Is transfer using socket the only way ? Do I necessarily  need to have a code running on the server and one on the client ?

Comment: If it's acceptable in your requirements to have your end-users also running a Java VM, you could consider wrapping your client code up in an applet. That way the end-user doesn't actually need to install the software, they can just visit a page that fires up the applet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have https server (apache, IIS...) on the machine you want to download from than you will need only the client. Unless your requirement is to write code for both server AND client.
On a general note: YES, in order to transfer file(s) between 2 computers over https you need BOTH server and client.

Comment: Thanks .. U helped me get a hang of things :)